# Sharepoint workflow very slow and sends multiple emails

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

We have multiple Sharepoint site collections and sites on a SharePoint 2013 farm.

Recently we have noticed a couple of issues with the workflows in the farm.

The workflows are very slow to process. Soetimes it takes 20 to 30 minutes to process a workflow step.

The workflows that send an email ofter send multiple copies of the same email, sometimes up to a 100 or more times.

The workflows were working with no issues until recently (probably 3 weeks ago)

Comment: Perhaps, you have incorrect designed workflow. Do you use loops in workflow? Attach schema of your workflow.

Comment: This is happening suddenly to workflows that have worked fine for years.  As far as I can see it is affecting all workflows and most don't have loops.